# Setting header when user clicks on a link

Tags: php, javascript

I would like to ask whether it is possible to set request header when user clicks on a link?

Answer (score 1):

No.

You would have to replace the link action by an Ajax request in order to set custom request headers.

Since version 1.5, jQuery.ajax() has [the `headers` object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for convenient access.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.. you link him to a page where you set the header and redirect him to the right page. :)

Or.. use javascript and hide the form and submit it on click :)

Answer (score 0):

Also it is use "get", u can use AJAX to get other content from another page then you can change the head  request .

like use jQuery.

```
$.get({});
$.post({});
```

I don't know what u want to do with that?